# How to turn off https route in laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7. When I press the login button to login, it automatically redirects me to HTTPS and shows "*This site can't be reached*". I checked through Chrome inspect window, form action was already set to `https://localhost/login`. I have set `APP_ENV` to `local`.

I wrote the login form like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: There are very many reasons this could be happening. Are you wanting ```http``` for all your routes, or only the login route you mentioned? What's the ```APP_URL``` in your ```.env``` file?

Comment: I want http for all routes. My APP_URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in .env file.

Comment: Try changing your ```APP_URL``` to ```APP_URL=http://localhost``` as well as add/modify ```FORCE_HTTPS``` to be false ```FORCE_HTTPS=false``` and see what happens. When you make these changes make sure you run ```php artisan config:clear``` as well as clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try these 2 steps:

1. Check your variables in .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost      //or anything that you want
```

2. run `php artisan config:cache`. Remember to run this command whenever you make some changes to your .env or config files
3. Try running the application using `php artisan serve`. In case you are using some other way to run the application.